# Quickest way to split a large file based on text within the file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a large file which contains data for 10 years. I want to split it into files that contain 1 year of data each.

The data in the file is in the following format:

GBPUSD,20100201,000200,1.5969,1.5969,1.5967,1.5967,4
GBPUSD,20100201,000300,1.5967,1.5967,1.5960,1.5962,4

Characters 8-11 contain the year. I would like to use that as the filename with .txt on the end. So 2011.txt, 2012.txt etc

The file contains around 4million rows.

I'm using Ubuntu Linux

Comment: @Fredrik as far as I understood from the example, each line would be a minute (000200 and 000300 look like 00:02 and 00:03).

Comment: No, there is one line per minute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ print > substr($0,8,4) ".txt" }' file
```

If the length of the first field can vary, you may prefer:

```
awk -F, '{ print > substr($2,0,4) ".txt" }' file
```

Comment: howabout using `>>` instead of `>` to append all lines belonging to a specific year into the same file?

Comment: @Fredrik: It's not necessary. The filehandles remain open until `awk` is finished.

Comment: There can't be more simpler solution that this

Comment: Thanks! Fwiw on OS X: this solution resulted in an error when using the `/usr/bin/awk` binary (as of OS X 10.8.5). Worked fine once I installed `gawk` from MacPorts.

Comment: @NoahSussman: You _can_ do this with BSD `awk`, try: `awk -F, '{ f = substr($2,0,4) ".txt"; print > f }' file`. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work from the command line:

`` YEARS=`cat FILE | sed -e 's/^.......//' -e 's/\(....\).*$/\1/' | sort | uniq` ; for Y in $YEARS ; do echo Processing $Y... ; egrep '^.......'$Y FILE > $Y.txt ; done ``

Comment: That would work, but if there are N years, this solution reads the source file (four million rows) N+1 times.  You should probably use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq` because maybe the `sort` program can work more efficiently if it knows it can throw away redundant lines... hmm, I ought to look at the source code for `sort` and see if that's true.

Comment: I was interpreting "quickest" in the title as total overall time spent splitting the file, including development time.  zio specified that the data is limited to only 10 years and 4 million lines, which should take at most a few seconds to iterate through 11 times.  If it's a one-off script (as it sounds from the requirements), those extra grep passes will save on development time.  I think Steve's AWK script beat mine there too, though.

Comment: "Development time" in this case already includes the time it takes for an answer to appear here, which is likely to dwarf the amount of time it takes to develop a solution that runs efficiently.

Comment: I wouldn't exclude others' time from what matters to zio for development time, if part of the reason for asking was to become familiar with techniques that would help to (quickly) solve similar problems in the future. Also, brevity and clarity of the solution will affect his overall implementation time. I'd argue that a one-off script that runs a few seconds faster isn't more efficient if it takes longer to understand, even if you do want to ignore the original author's development time.  (Yes, Steve did a much better job of producing an understandable solution with his AWK script than I did.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to read through the file once, and write each line to the file where it should go.  So the solution by @steve using AWK is a good one.

You could solve this problem using `grep` and an appropriate regular expression: `^.......2010` would only match lines that have `2010` in the year position.  Then a shell script could loop over the years and keep running `grep`, something like this:

```
for year in 2010 2011 2012; do
    grep "^.......$year" datafile > $year.txt
done
```

But it's not elegant because it reads the whole source file once per year.

Here's a Python solution to go along with the AWK one.

```
import sys

def next_line():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        for line in sys.stdin:
            yield line
    else:
        for name in sys.argv[1:]:
            with open(name) as f:
                for line in f:
                    yield line


_open_files = {}
def output(fname, line):
    if fname not in _open_files:
        _open_files[fname] = open(fname, "w")
    _open_files[fname].write(line)


for line in next_line():
    year = line[7:11]
    fname = year + ".txt"
    output(fname, line)
```

AWK certainly wins for brevity.  I had to implement function `next_line()` to provide a service that offers up source lines from each file in turn, or standard input if you didn't specify a file; with AWK you get that for free.  I had to implement function `output()` to let you just provide a filename and a string and write the output, but with AWK you get that for free.

If your problem will not ever get more complicated you could use the AWK solution, but if you expect to add more bells and whistles as time goes by, the Python solution might pay off.  (That's why I love Python... once you have it working, it's easy to extend it no matter what you need to do.)